# Данные из react-native fetch() не отображаются в приложении

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-native, fetch, react-hook

Я новичок в React Native,пробую подключить fetch к Firebase, мне пришел ответ, но данные не отображаются в приложении(просто пустой экран), при этом в консоль выводятся без проблем. Ошибок никаких в консоли нет. Не могу понять в чем дело.

файл Reducer.js

```
import { FETCH_REST } from "../types";

const initialState = {
    allRests: [],
    chosen: []
};

export const restReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_REST: 
            return{...state,
                 allRests: action.payload,  
                 chosen: action.payload.filter(r => r.chosen)}
  default: return state
    }   
}
```

файл Actions.js

```
import {FETCH_REST} from "../types"

              export const fetchRest = async () => {
                const response = await fetch("https://res-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/data.json",{
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                })
                const data= await response.json()
                console.log("data:\n" ,data);
                return{
                    type: FETCH_REST,
                    payload: data
                }
            }
```

файл где используются данные из fetch - Homescreen.js

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { MenuCard } from '../menuCard/MenuCard';
import { fetchRest } from '../store/actions/Action';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const loadData= useCallback(async () => await fetchRest(), [fetchRest])
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData()
  },[])

  const allRests = useSelector(state => state.rest.allRests)
  
  return (
    <View>
        <MenuCard data={allRests} navigation={navigation} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

store.js

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {Reducer} from './reducers/Reducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    rest: Reducer
});

export default createStore(rootReducer);
```

Буду рад любому совету, как вывести данные для отображения. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А почему бы вам просто не использовать уже готовый SDK firebase? https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase . Документацию пишут, не просто так.

Comment: @Александр, спасибо, но я не думаю что проблема в сервере. В консоль я могу вывести ответ от fetch в массиве, но при этом в приложении данные не отображаются. Временно работаю с данными из подключенного файла js и в приложении все отображается. Такое ощущение, что из fetch данные не доходят в компонент для отрисовки, но я не могу понять почему.

Comment: Сложно создать песочницу для react-native, наблюдается небольшой уровень лентяйства. Вам все еще нужна помощь или вы уже нашли решение?

Comment: И как вариант попробуйте убрать `async` функцию из `action` и перенести ее в `useEffect` с `callBack`-ом. И когда данные прийду, тогда передать уже данные в `action`.

Comment: @Александр, попробовал то, что вы сказали, результат тот же - данные приходят, в консоль выводятся, а в компоненте не отображаются. Буду очень благодарен если поможете.